# Calculate monthly returns from a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, gini

I have been asked to calculate the Gini coefficient (dispersion of allocation weighting) in 18 sectoral ETFs with historical data available since 2000. Here is an excerpt:

```
> head(df)
        Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR
1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39
2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92
3 2000-01-05 338.22 215.88 464.20 542.29 298.22 239.55 373.26 383.48 272.54 430.05
4 2000-01-06 343.13 218.18 470.82 529.33 300.69 249.75 377.26 383.48 272.47 434.15
5 2000-01-07 349.46 220.10 478.87 531.65 306.50 255.17 381.19 390.23 273.76 447.02
6 2000-01-10 356.20 223.01 484.07 581.82 310.84 252.75 387.74 393.75 278.76 453.80
```

If you know an easier way to do it than my attempt I would be happy to hear it !

### My attempt

I know that the index **G** is equal to [image: Enter the description of the image here]

Where **E** is the average of all the deviations in absolute value for all the pairs of the statistical variable studied:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

And **M** is the average income:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yet, while computing the mean of the `portfolio_monthly_returns`, **M** I have this error: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.

From a friend's idea I create `portfolio_monthly_returns` with :

```
library(quantmod)
portfolio_monthly_returns=lapply(xts(df[,-1],order.by = df$Date),monthlyReturn) # What is monthlyReturn here ?
```

I don't get this code and it looks weird indeed:

[image]

```
> mean(portfolio_monthly_returns)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(portfolio_monthly_returns) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

### Data

The data file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

In order to get `df`:

```
library (dplyr)
library (lubridate)
   
df <- read.xlsx ("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df [2:19] <- data.matrix (df [2:19])
```

#### Remark

I don't know why it doesn't involve the weights:

```
cov = cor(NewData)
# ERC algorithm
Sigma = cov
w = optimalPortfolio(Sigma = Sigma,control = list(type = 'erc', constraint = 'lo'))

w = matrix(w, 1, 18)
(Sigma %*% t(w)) * c(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're looking to calculate *G* for each column of `df`. In that case this function applied to each column of `df` will give you *G* provided that your equations for *E* and *M* are exactly what you want and that the *x<sub>k</sub>*'s are the elements of the column:

```
gini_calc <- function (x) {
    #Strip out NA elements
    x_no_na <- x[!is.na(x)]

    #This matrix calculation gives a matrix of all differences of the elements, after which E and M can be calculated
    mat <- matrix(rep(x_no_na, length(x_no_na)), ncol=length(x_no_na))
    E <- sum(abs(mat-t(mat)))/length(x_no_na)^2
    M <- mean(x_no_na)

    #Return G
    return(E/(2*M))
}
```

From here you can simply use `lapply` on `df`. This assumes that you don't want to include `NA` in any of the calculations.

I'd make sure that this function does exactly what you want. It's unclear to me why you're using `monthlyReturn` and such.